# react Unable to retrieve the contents of an object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using `react`.
I want to display the name of the object retrieved using `find`.

When I look at `currentValue()` in `console.log()`, I can see that the object has been retrieved. However, when I try to display the name of the retrieved object (`currentValue().name`), I get an error.
If anyone knows the reason, I would appreciate it if you could tell me.

error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
```

```
  const [state, setState] = useState<{id: number, name: string}[]>([])

  const currentValue = () => {
    return state.find((s) => {
      return s.name === props.groups.name;
    });
  };

　　　　console.log(currentValue())
  console.log(currentValue().name)
```

Comment: Please add the complete code of the component.

Comment: could you add more code?

Answer (score -1):

What if you structure the code in this way?
Because in the current way, you are not passing a variable to the method when invoking it, so it cannot refer anything.

```
const [state, setState] = useState<{id: number, name: string}[]>([])

const find = (id: number) => {
   return state.find((_s) => { return _s.id === id; });
};
```

Comment: OP is using `props` instead of passing a parameter, which is a totally valid way of using data inside a function without using any parameters.

Comment: i think the question need to have more code and more insight @EmileBergeron

Answer (score -2):

currentValue() is your function and when you are calling that function at that time you are getting values returned for it.

So you can't directly call `currentValue().name` it is not making any sense here.

So just `const obj = currentValue()` is the solution according to your code.

Then you will get object return from curretValue();

Now just do obj. value you want to get.